# Can't compile with time- and clock-related functions C++

Tags: c++, time, build, clock

I starting [my first GNU project](https://github.com/FoxEmu/FoxEmu) based on [another GNU project](https://github.com/Elyotna/IntWars) to improve upon it and change the implementation.

I tried to implement my own build method, but time- and clock-related functions broke my build.

I've read a lot of questions on Stack Overflow, but I very confused with the three libraries `chrono`, `ctime` and `time.h`.

This is the build errors:

**/src/gamed/Logger.cpp**

```
#include "Logger.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <stdarg.h>

#include <time.h>

const std::string Logger::CurrentDateTime()
{
    time_t     now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char       buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %X", &tstruct);

    return buf;
}
```

Error: time, localtime and strftime identifier not found

**/src/gamed/Packets.h**

```
#ifndef _PACKETS_H
#define _PACKETS_H

#include <time.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <set>

{...}

class GamePacket : public BasePacket {

public:
   GamePacket(uint8 cmd = 0, uint32 netId = 0) : BasePacket(cmd, netId) {
      buffer << (uint32)clock();
   }

};
```

> Error: clock identifier not found

**/src/gamed/Pathfinder.cpp**

```
#include "Logger.h"
#include "Pathfinder.h"
#include "Map.h"
#include "AIMesh.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include "Logger.h"
#include "Minion.h"
#include "Champion.h"

Map * Pathfinder::chart = 0;
auto g_Clock = std::clock();
```

> Error: clock isn't member of std

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `#include <ctime>` not `time.h`.

Comment: @ForEveR: I replaced time.h with <ctime> and make a lot of errors on  #if _GLOBAL_USING && !defined(RC_INVOKED)
_STD_BEGIN
using _CSTD clock_t; using _CSTD size_t;
using _CSTD time_t; using _CSTD tm;
using _CSTD asctime; using _CSTD clock; using _CSTD ctime;
using _CSTD difftime; using _CSTD gmtime; using _CSTD localtime;
using _CSTD mktime; using _CSTD strftime; using _CSTD time;
_STD_END
 #endif /* _GLOBAL_USING */
#endif /* _CTIME_ */

Comment: @Angivare: I replaced std::clock() with clock() but still errors

Comment: @AhriLoveDev what compiler are you using?

Comment: @ user2079303: Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on Windows 8.1, but I have travis-ci on the repository and show errors too: https://travis-ci.org/FoxEmu/FoxEmu

Comment: @AhriLoveDev the errors originate from the standard headers and seems to be a compatibility issue with the compiler.

Comment: @AhriLoveDev Do you happen to `#define` `_SYS_TIME_H` or `_TIME_H` or something similar in *any* of your headers or as a parameter to the compiler? That would probably cause the errors that you have in travis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I very confused with the three libraries chrono, ctime and time.h.

There's only 2 libraries in that sentence. `<chrono>` is part of the c++ standard library and was introduced in c++11 version of the standard. None of your code seem to use anything from `<chrono>`. `<time.h>` is part of the c standard library. `<ctime>` is a header in c++ standard library which wraps `<time.h>` inside `std` namespace instead of global namespace which is the only "namespace" in c.

```
#include <time.h>
// ....
auto g_Clock = std::clock();
```

> Error: clock isn't member of std

You included the c header but try to refer to the `std` namespace. That is not correct. Include `<ctime>` instead so that `clock` will be in `std`.

```
#include <time.h>
// ...
time_t     now = time(0);
```

> Error: time (...) identifier not found

At a glance, your code there seems correct. Double check that's actually the code you're compiling and getting the errors from. Here's simplified version of that function which compiles fine http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/664f568053103f32

Stylewise, I wouldn't recommend mixing `<cXXX>` and `<XXX.h>` headers. Pick one.

Comment: I replaced all <time.h> with <ctime>, all clock() with std::clock(), but still have build errors. A lot of this on ctime library: 'clock_t' is not member of global namespace, 'asctime' is not member of global namespace,  'clock' is not member of global namespace,  'difftime' is not member of global namespace...

Comment: @AhriLoveDev Create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Preferably just one file which contains `main` and reproduces the build error. Then post it in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Solved!

The problem is the project use enet library, and has time.h, renaming file to enet_time.h the build work great (It's temporary fix, I think is better using namespaces).

Thanks to all and sorry for the inconvenients, I learn more of wrapping C libraries into C++ thanks to all responses.

A greeting

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you should use the "c" prefix on all your C-library `#include`s.

So `#include <time.h>` should become: `#include <ctime>`.

But note that when you use `#include <ctime>` everything in time.h will now be in the `std` namespace.

So `clock()` must become `std::clock()`.

For more info see: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/include-c-hdrs-system.html

Comment: Replaced all clock() by std::clock() but visual studio 2013 report: clock is not member of std